# Why $pull operator doesn't work on MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("581472c3c65f3a1b3412f147"),
"name" : "这是一级目录-----1",
"englishName" : "zzzzz",
"stage" : "first",
"children" : [ 
    ObjectId("581472f1c65f3a1b3412f149"), 
    ObjectId("581472f4c65f3a1b3412f14a")
],
"type" : "group",
"order" : 50,
"__v" : 0
}
```

I want to remove children[1] by `$pull`, but it doesn't work.

```
var _id = req.fields._id;   //581472f4c65f3a1b3412f14a
var parent_id = req.fields.parent;  //581472c3c65f3a1b3412f147
db.Group.update({ _id: parent_id }, { $pull:{children:_id} },function(err,result){
                    console.log(result);
                    cb(err,result);
                })
```

I have try to use `{$pull:{children:ObjectId(_id)}}` instead of  `{ $pull:{children:_id} }` ,but still failed.

**Mongoose Schema**

```
var groupSchema=new Schema({
  name:String,
  englishName:String,
  order:{
    type:Number,
    default:50
  },
  type:{
    type:String,
    default:"group"
  },
  stage:String,
  children:{
    type:Array,
    default:[]
  }
});
```

My English is very poor. Please forgive me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have use the following way to solve this problem.

when use `$push` to `children`. use `{$push:{children:_id.toString()}}` instead of `{$push:{children:_id}}`. And it wont't effect query-object